# Looking for a way to deploy my wordpress sites (git-repository)

Tags: wordpress, git, deployment, bitbucket

So currently I try to set up a new workflow. This is what I currently have:

I work with VVV so I have such structure:

```
xyz.de.dev/
---- .git/
---- bower_components/
---- node_modules/
---- wp-content/
---- wp-includes/
---- wp-admin/
---- .gitignore
---- other WP files...
```

So that is my git-powered local development environment of the project. I also set up a private bitbucket project and I'm pushing my local dev to that project using "git push origin master".

Now I have a Webserver which should act as a staging server. I have SSH access and git is installed on that server.

Which would be the best way to deploy my local development to a staging or later a live server? I already tried to clone the bitbucket project to my staging server and then, git pull every time I updated the project. But that didnt work out as expected.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

> Which would be the best way to deploy my local development to a staging or later a live server?

My colleague built something your are looking for for our company website:

1. Create a remote branch to release on your server (e.g. Remote)
2. Merge your current version from your Development-branch into your Remote-branch
3. create a dump-file of your wordpress database (you can write a script that will do this automatically when you commit)
4. fetch and pull your changes on your server
5. Importing your dump on the server. You have to write a script, that search and replace path (different from your local path) and I guess your login is different to your local db.

I hope this helps you in your further considerations.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with git by now. Isnt that the same as cloning the repository to my dir on the staging server? When I do that and then "git status" its says there are modied and deleted files. But I just did a git pull and it said everything is up-to-date.

Comment: No, because wordpress do a lot of changes in the db and not in the files who were tracked by git. You have to commit your changes from your workspace and push them before you can pull it.

Comment: Yeah that was not unclear but I seemed to have another problem. I dont know how, but I fixed it.... Sorry, would like to share it but I dont know what made it